# How do I hide 'this' image on hover using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains two elements surrounded by an anchor tag. When the page loads the image is visible and the info_overlay div content is hidden.

I want to hide the image and show the info_overlay div when I mouseover the anchor tag.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="project">
<a class="project_link" href="/reap-renewable-energy-and-preservation">
<img src="/photos/reap-home-page-copy.jpg" alt="REAP" >

<div class="info_overlay" style="display:none;">
<h3>REAP</h3>
<p></p>
<p><a href="project/reap-renewable-energy-and-preservation">VIEW</a></p>
</div><!-- end info_overlay -->
</a>
</div><!-- end project -->
```

Here is the jQuery. So far, I have it so that when you mouse over the image, all of the images disappear. I want to just target 'this' image so that it disappears, but I can't quite get the syntax.

```
$( "a.project_link" ).hover(function() {
  $( "img" ).hide(  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do like this:

```
$("a.project_link").hover(function () {
    $(this).find("img").hide();
    $(this).next(".info_overlay").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find("img").show();
    $(this).next(".info_overlay").hide();

});
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/hMvMW/)

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/hMvMW/1/)

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/hMvMW/2/)

Comment: Ehsan, thanks for the quick reply. The next() option works best. Is there a way to have the image come back when I mouse out?

Comment: you have to write another event

Comment: where have you implemented this on page?

Comment: Please see lines 80-85

Comment: unable to find it please provide a proper fiddle

Comment: @fmz found replace ``$(this).find(".image").hide();`` with ``$(this).find("img").hide();``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56986/discussion-between-fmz-and-ehsan-sajjad).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(this).parent().find('img').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this, you can do it with a CSS `:hover` pseudo selector:

```
a.project_link:hover img { display: none; }
a.project_link:hover .info_overlay { display: block; }
```

And if you want smooth transitions:

```
a.project_link * { transition:all .2s linear; -moz-transition:all .2s linear; -webkit-transition:all .2s linear; }
```

Was there a reason you wanted to do it with jQuery?